# Advice and feedback on dividing cash amounts into actual counts of various bills and coinage

Tags: vba

So I need an idea of how to divide out an amount of money into actual counts of various bills and coinage. I know this is confusing, so let me give an example:

```
$16.32 - Sixteen dollars and thirty-two cents
One $10 bill
One $5 bill
One $1 bill
One Quarter ($0.25)
One Nickel ($0.05)
Two Pennies ($0.01)
```

So as you can see, we're just getting the number of bills and coinage that goes into a value, which will change according to user input.

Here's my current setup (Visual Basic):

```
If 100 Mod amount < 0 Then
    If 50 Mod amount < 0 Then
         ' Continue this pattern until you get all the way down to the end ($0.01)
    Else  
        While amount > 50
            fiftiesAmount += 1
            amount -= 50
    End If
Else 
    While amount > 100 
        hundredsAmount += 1
        amount -= 100
End If
```

Basically, each `If` statement determines whether or not your total amount needs an extra billing amount of that type, and then either adds to the amount of bills/coinage already created or moves on to the next amount.

Is this an efficient way of doing things, or am I missing out on an easier/faster algorithm/pattern that would make my life, and whoever is reading my code's life easier?
If you need extra details, I'll be happy to edit the question as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your amount to cents (it's easier). Divide by the currency value being tested, and then deduct that amount from the balance (pseudo-code)

```
Value = 16.32 * 100                  ' Convert to cents
If Value > 10000                     ' Hundreds
  Hundreds = Value / 10000           ' How many?
  Value = Value - (Hundreds * 10000) ' Reduce amount accordingly
End If

If Value > 5000                      ' Fifties
  Fifties = Value / 5000
  Value = Value - (Fifties * 5000)   
End If

If Value > 2000                      ' Twenties
  Twenties = Value / 2000
  Value = Value - (Twenties * 2000)
End If
```

Repeat until you have less than 100, at which point you start with coins (50, 25, 10, 5)
Once you've got > 10, you've reached pennies; save them, reduce Value by that amount, and
Value is zero, so you're finished.